# For what values of $z$ is $\sin z$ real/imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

For what values of $z$ is $\sin z$, $\cos z$ and $\tan z$ real/imaginary.

If someone points me in the right direction for the first one I think I will be able to solve the rest on my own.

Comment: How do you define $\sin \sqrt {-1}$?

Comment: @Apurv: $$\sin\sqrt{-1}=\dfrac{e^{i\sqrt{-1}}-e^{-i\sqrt{-1}}}{2i}$$http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiFiaijzNXIAhWDWY4KHXQWDDA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FSine.html&usg=AFQjCNFzg2an_d3ETQaIJNnq56DFO4pbwQ

Comment: @Nilan, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin z=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$ real part$=0$ then $\sin(x)\cosh(y)=0$ iff $sinx=0\Rightarrow x=k\pi$.

Imaginary part $=0 \Rightarrow \cos(x)\sinh(y)=0$ thus $\cos x=0$ or $\sinh y=0$ which for first one $x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ anf for the second one $y=0$

Comment: $$\sin z=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$

This I have never seen before, can you tell me how to derive it? You don't have to do it yourself if you don't want to, just tell me how? You write $\sin z$ in the exponential form and then add and subtract something?

Comment: see page 2 of www.math.duke.edu/~wka/math114/e.pdf

Comment: Cheers! Now I will manage! :)